# Square made from other real squares

Tags: geometry, real-numbers

[A recent Numberphile video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NoRjwZomUK0) discusses integer sided squares made out of unique smaller integer sided squares. The smallest such square has been proven to use 21 rectangles.

It's clear that for rational sided squares that result is also optimal, because if there was an arrangement that used less than 21 rectangles every side could be multiplied by the least common multiple of all denominators to form a solution where every side length is integer.

What about the real number case? Without loss of generality, what is the smallest amount of unique squares with **real** sides such that they can be arranged to exactly cover the unit square?

Comment: You should check out Wikipedia's article on  [Squaring the Square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squaring_the_square)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any decomposition of the unit square into a finite number of squares
always involves just squares of rational sides. This follows from the
relation to electrical networks as described in say Bollobas's *Graph Theory*. To work out the side-lengths in any possible configuration
one must solve a system of linear equations. In each case that solution
is unique, and as the system has rational coefficients, the solution
is always rational.

Answer (score 0):

Any decomposition of a rectangle (including squares) where the sides are rational multiples of each other into rectangles has every region have a rational side.  As I remember this gets fourteen different proofs in [Proofs from the Book](http://www.springer.com/br/book/9783642008566), but I can't find it in my old edition.  The new chapter is Tiling Rectangles.  I have read it, but it must not be in the version I have.